# Null instead of null values in jsonb_build_object

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build query that gets data from 3 different tables using sqlalchemy

I tried

```
select(
    models.Animals.id,
    models.Animals.description,
    models.AnimalTypes.name.label('type'),
        func.coalesce(
            func.array_agg(
                func.jsonb_build_object(
                    'id',
                     models.Animals.id
                     )
                ), None
            ).label('animals')
     )
         .join(models.FamilyTypes, models.Family.id == models.Family.family_type_id)
         .outerjoin(models.Animals, models.Animals.campaign_id == models.Animals.id)
         .group_by(models.Family.id, models.FamilyType.name)
```

i expect to get animals:`null` instead of animals:`{"id": null}`

Comment: 1) FYI, you are switching type from JSON to Postgres array with `array_agg`. I am not sure exactly what the query is supposed  to be ding but I am pretty sure that is not helping. 2) I would work this query out in `psql` first then move to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I think you are looking for `json_object_agg` from [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) e.g `json_object_agg(id) from rewards`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver tried to use it but don't really get how it works. I need an array of json objects and as I understand `json_object_agg` creates only one key: value object

Comment: See my 'answer' for something closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this using `case`

```
    case(
        (func.count(models.Animals.id) == 0, None),
        else_=(
            func.array_agg(
                func.jsonb_build_object(
                    'id',
                     models.Animals.id,
                     ...
                     )
                )
             ),
    ).label('animals')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a longer comment. Using `psql` on a local test table. Using `jsonb_agg` from [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
 select jsonb_agg(animals.*) from animals;
test(5432)=# select * from animals;
 pk_animals | cond  | animal 
------------+-------+--------
          2 | good  | eagle
          3 | good  | mole
         16 | fair  | heron
         33 | fair  | mole
        200 | good  | crow
         35 | good  | emu
        101 | good  | gopher
         45 | poor  | dog
         50 | great | deer

\pset format wrapped
select jsonb_agg(animals.*) from animals;
                                                                                     jsonb_agg                                                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"cond": "good", "animal": "eagle", "pk_animals": 2}, {"cond": "good", "animal": "mole", "pk_animals": 3}, {"cond": "fair", "animal": "heron", "pk_animals": 16}, {"cond": "fair.
.", "animal": "mole", "pk_animals": 33}, {"cond": "good", "animal": "crow", "pk_animals": 200}, {"cond": "good", "animal": "emu", "pk_animals": 35}, {"cond": "good", "animal": "g.
.opher", "pk_animals": 101}, {"cond": "poor", "animal": "dog", "pk_animals": 45}, {"cond": "great", "animal": "deer", "pk_animals": 50}]
```